# Report Builder 3.0 Reapply a filter multiple times

Tags: filter, parameters, reportbuilder3.0

I have report with a parameter that I'm trying to use to filter the results.  This is the expression I'm using for the filter:

```
=(Parameters!REPORT_FILTER.Value = 6 And Fields!Filter3.Value = 1) OR
(Parameters!REPORT_FILTER.Value = 5 And Fields!Filter2.Value = 2) OR
(Parameters!REPORT_FILTER.Value = 4 And Fields!Filter2.Value = 1) OR
(Parameters!REPORT_FILTER.Value = 3 And Fields!Filter1.Value = 2) OR
(Parameters!REPORT_FILTER.Value = 2 And Fields!Filter1.Value = 1) OR
(Parameters!REPORT_FILTER.Value = 1 And Fields!Filter1.Value = 1 OR    
Fields!Filter1.Value = 2)
```

The user picks an option from the parameter drop down to select an option:

```
All (value = 1)
Home Group (Value = 2)
Home Branch (Value = 3)
Other Group  (Value =4)
Other Branch (Value = 5)
Shared Services (Value = 6)
```

The query selects all of the appropriate records and puts either a 1 or a 2 in the Filter1, Filter2, or Filter3 column.  I've checked these columns and they have the right value.

It appears that the first time the report is run, it displays the correct records.  My question is "Can I change the filter parameter and hit the "View Report" button to display the results based on the "new" parameter value?  Can you use a filter over and over on the same dataset once the report has been run?  Thanks for the help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Cached Dataset on your report server and set an expiration time before clicking "View Report" will trigger another query to the database. You will receive quick results each time that you click "View Report" within that time-span, since the flat cached data stored on your report server will feed the report.

Note that if your parameter is used within the SQL query that generates the dataset, the cache will be useless since it will need to regenerate the dataset for this new parameter. But if you are only filtering the dataset in the report, this will work.

For more info on setting up a shared dataset and enabling caching:

[Cache Shared Datasets (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee636149.aspx)

[Manage Shared Datasets (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee636147.aspx)

Comment: ........Thanks for the information.  This is going to be helpful.  I appreciate your response